# Publishing certain paths of a private git repository

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm working with a team of ~10 devs on a **private gitlab repository** containing the following projects:

1. Server
2. AI
3. Client
4. Interface
5. Misc (Protocols, PR Material, etc.)

Each of which — apart from *Misc* — has their own **Maven** dependencies and unit tests contained in their specific folder.

We are using `git-flow`, so all of the branches will be merged with one `develop` branch at some point.

---

**Question:**

> We are currently only selling the **Client & Interface** with source and would like to grant our clients access to only these (sub-)projects, including their history, while being able to easily push updates and also using gitlab's `issues` functionality.

**Ideas I had:**

1. If it would be a public repo, I would simply use `git submodules`, but this solution does not seem to work flawlessly with **private** repositories. (If at all — Have read a lot about trouble with invalid paths)
2. If I had super-clean branches for the `Client` and `Interface`, I could add another fresh `remote` repository and simply push these two branches to it. Problem with this solution is, that we have inexperienced devs on board and one dirty push or one push from the `develop` branch would basically render this whole idea useless. The risk is too high.
3. Another idea I had was moving these 2 sub-projects out of the private repo, creating submodules *within* the private repo. Which somehow also feels pretty inconvenient, because our `continuous integration` would run in a different repo and also our own issues would be tracked there.

Since this is a pretty specific setup and plan, I would be interested in your ideas to solve a situation like this. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will update this post if a more elegant solution is found or we experience trouble.

***This solution also publishes the git-history of your project.*** Depending on how cleanly your team worked beforehand, you can filter it out, though: [Git Documentation on how to do this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History). You should perform this step after cleaning the branch(es).

**The idea behind this solution is to...**

1. Create super clean branches including only the directories to deploy
2. Then pulling these branches into a new repository
3. Control-Step to check if the branches are clean and ready for deployment
4. Deployment

**Assure you have another backup and test this thoroughly.** We are using a force command at some point. This worked flawlessly on *OUR* repository, but may cause side effects I'm not yet aware of. If you encounter them, please let me know so that I can update this entry.

> Steps to perform on `private local repository`:

```
# Assure we are on the latest stable state within our main repo
git checkout <CURRENT_STATE>

# Create a new deployment branch from HEAD
git branch <DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH> HEAD

# Enter the new branch
git checkout <DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH>
```

**[Option 1]:** If you intend to remove the directory's path structure and deploy all files into the root directory of your new repository, use the following strategy

```
# Filter every comment outside of this subdirectory (execute from root directory of repo)
git filter-branch -f --subdirectory-filter <DIRECTORY_PATH> -- <DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH>
```

**[Option 2]:** Filter and keep directory tree

```
##
# Force filter-branch using the tree-filter (keeps the 
# directory-structure) while deleting all files outside    
# this directory (Check if you are on <DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH>
# first). Folders are kept, but since Git does not push 
# empty folders this is no problem

git filter-branch --tree-filter -f \
    'find . -path <DIRECTORY_PATH> -prune -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f' \
    --prune-empty HEAD
```

We would like to add the `master` branch's `.gitignore` file.

```
# Take master .gitignore and add it to the branch
git checkout master -- .gitignore
```

You should also update it to ignore all other directories, but your `<DIRECTORY_PATH>`:

```
##
# In .gitignore:
# Ignore everything:
*

# Except for these directories:

!path/
!path/*/
!.gitignore
```

Stage and commit these changes:

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Add .gitignore"
```

> Inform your fellow devs to track the new branch within their `private local repositories`:

```
##
# If you would pull this branch, Git would attempt a merge it into your current HEAD.
# Do NOT pull! Instead start tracking the remote branch

git checkout --track origin/<DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH>
```

> Steps to perform on new `destination / deployment repository`

Clone or create the `destination / deployment repository`. Inside of it add a remote to our `private local repository` and pull / merge branches into master:

```
# Add remote to local private repo
git remote add local <PATH/TO/PRIVATE/REPO/.git>

git checkout master
```

**[Option 1]:** Pull and therefore merge changes directly into master

```
# Pull changes from private repo and allow unrelated histories

git pull local <DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH> --allow-unrelated-histories
```

**[Option 2]:** Track branches without instant merge

```
# Track branches for more granular control
git checkout --track local/<DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH>
```

> Deployment:

```
# Deploy option 1: (For option 2 simply push your tracked branches)
git push origin master
```